# Getting an error ORA:00907 while I am writing a case statement

Tags: oracle11g

the below case statement in Oracle gives me an error. Please help. The error is : ORA:00907.

```
select * from schools_master_table where  TEST_SUBJECT_KEY in  (case 
when SCHOOL_YEAR<=2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (3,4,5,6,7,8,10) THEN (1,2,3,4,5)
when SCHOOL_YEAR >2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (10) THEN (1,3)
when SCHOOL_YEAR>2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (3,4,5,6,7,8) THEN (1,2,3,4,5)
when SCHOOL_YEAR>2014 and TEST_TYPE_KEY in (11) THEN  (17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
ELSE NULL 
END)
```

Comment: I am trying to write a case statement in which if condition 1 is satisfied then test_subject_key is (1,2,3,4,5) else condition 2 or condition 3 and so on.

Comment: Edit your original post and add the above comment to it so that it is more relevant. Also add more tags, such as oracle, sql, etc to get more people to help

Comment: This just isn't valid [case expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm), or providing a valid list for the `in` condition. You can't have a list of values as the result  of a case (unless you use a collection). Does your assignment require you to use a case, and if so what does it specify? Otherwise this should be done with `or` and `and` operators and si ole conditions, not case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [case expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm) allows return expressions and an else expression. The important thing here is that is need to be [an expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions001.htm), "... that evaluates to a value". You're trying to return [an expression list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions015.htm) instead, and that isn't valid in the case construct. You can see that with a simple example:

```
select case when 1=1 then (1,2) end from dual;
```

which also gets `ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis` and the error is marked as being where the comma is - because it's expecting to see the closing parenthesis from a set around a single expression, not a list.

You can just use a combination of `OR` and `AND` instead, checking the `TEST_KEY_SUBJECT` value against the appropriate list when the other conditions match:

```
select * from schools_master_table
where (SCHOOL_YEAR<=2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (3,4,5,6,7,8,10)
  and  TEST_SUBJECT_KEY in (1,2,3,4,5))
or (SCHOOL_YEAR>2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (10)
  and TEST_SUBJECT_KEY in (1,3))
or (SCHOOL_YEAR>2014 and TEST_GRADE_KEY in (3,4,5,6,7,8)
  and TEST_SUBJECT_KEY in (1,2,3,4,5))
or (SCHOOL_YEAR>2014 and TEST_TYPE_KEY in (11)
  and TEST_SUBJECT_KEY in (17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25))
```

Comment: Alex, thank you so much. Not sure why I was hell-bent on using case. Appreciate it!